# Why does this code print two error messages instead of one?

Tags: python, json

So I was making a test code that reads in json and you have to input the value to access:

```
import json

f = "keys.json"
data = json.loads(open(f).read())

username = input("User: ")
key = input("Key: ")

for item in data:
    if item['user'] != username:
        print("Incorrect username.")
    elif item['key'] != key:
        print("Incorrect key.")
    else:
        print(f"Welcome, {username}.")
```

And this is what the json file looks:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "user": "susan",
    "key": "yes"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user": "susana",
    "key": "yess"
  }
]
```

And this is the output:

```
User: susan
Key: yes
Welcome, susan.
Incorrect username.
```

It prints the correct verification and the incorrect verification, but only username, because if key is incorrect it prints like this:

```
User: susan
Key: e
Incorrect key.
Incorrect username.
```

What I can do to delete the second message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried to fix the problem yourself? To me it looks like the problem is occurring because the loop continues longer than you want. Have you considered stopping it earlier? You know how to use `break`, right? For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. After a successful verification, you don't want to continue the `for` loop – use the `break` command.
2. If the `for` loop is exhausted (i.e., no `break` command was performed) it means that the correspondent record was not found. Use the `else:` branch of the `for` loop to inform about a fail:

```
for item in data:
    if item['user'] == username and item['key'] == key:
        print(f"Welcome, {username}.")
        break
else:
    print("Incorrect username or key.")
```

---

*Notes:*

1. This code don't reveal, what part is incorrect, so a potential intruder will have less information.
2. Yes, the `for` loop may have the `else:` branch, too. It is performed if (and only if) the `for` loop is fully exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**: the problem is that you have two elements in the json file, as it loop through the list,it runs the print function for all elements.

**Solution**: put an addtional if check at the beginning of the loop to prevent any output from other failed cases.

```
flag = False
for item in data:
    # skip if username doesn't match
    if item['user'] == username:
        # check if password matches
        if item['key'] != key:
            print("Incorrect key.")
        else:
            print(f"Welcome, {username}.")
        flag = True
if not flag:
    print("Incorrect username.")
```

Comment: It does the same

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you do not break out of the loop when you do find a successful match.  I would recommend however learning the built in array methods like: `filter`, `find`, etc.

In this case you could make your code much easier by saying:

```js
   // [...] the input code is fine
   // Find in data an item that has the username and key == to our inputs
   var user = data.find( item => item.user == username && item.key == key )
   if(user) {
      print(f"Welcome, {username}")
   }
   else {
      print("Incorrect username or key.")
   }
```

If you were to do it the older more manual way:

```js
    var found = false;
    for item in data:
      if item['user'] == username && item['key'] == key {
         print (f"Welcome, {username}")
         found = true;
         break;
      } 
    }
    if !found 
       print("Incorrect username or key")
```

Comment: It is not a Python code. :-)